# Retrieving array back from database server android?

Tags: php, android, arrays, json

I'm new to android development My server takes in a few values makes required calculations and queries for a list of values that need to be sent back to the device(app) the php script returns an array of the form

```
["12345","999989892","9888889898","9876543513","9876543210","9876543211"]
```

I need to convert this json_encode array into an simple array in android.

```
try{
            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/tech/serverConnection.php");
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            is = entity.getContent();

            try{
            ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler=new BasicResponseHandler();
            String responseBody = httpClient.execute(httpPost, responseHandler);
            JSONArray test = new JSONArray(responseBody);
            resultArray = test.join(",").split(",");}
            catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();}
            }
    catch(ClientProtocolException e){
        Log.e("ClientProtocol", "Log_tag");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch(IOException e){
        Log.e("Log_tag", "IOException");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

when I try to display any of the numbers(lets say resultArray[1]) the I get a null pointer exception. I'm assuming the problem to either be with my response or parsing the array. The program works without errors while sending data to the server only problem occurs when I try to get data back from it.
Thank you for any help.

Comment: So `resultArray` is null? and is so, is `test` null?

Comment: Thank you @inmyth your answer worked once I sorted out my php script. I have one error though when the server returns an empty array it gives an Index out of bound error.

Comment: First of all how does your response look like ? "12345","999989892",... or ["12345","999989892",... (with bracket) ?

Comment: I just realized the first value is taken as ["1234" and not "1234". would it be considered a poor method if I just detect the ' [ ' and delete it?

Comment: In that case your response should be parsed as JSONArray. I am sorry I misunderstood your question. My answer works simply because it finds the commas in the response. You can try `JSONArray test = new JSONArray(responseBody);` and to get an element `String thetwo = test.get(2);`

Answer (score 0):

you shouldnt be joining the array or splitting it with a comma. you should be doing this

```
JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(responseBody);
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
for(int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++){
    list.add(arr.getJSONObject(i).toString());
}
```

then you can do list.get(x) to get the string

Comment: W/SingleClientConnManager(2508): Invalid use of SingleClientConnManager: connection still allocated.
W/SingleClientConnManager(2508): Make sure to release the connection before allocating another one.
 W/System.err(2508): org.json.JSONException: Value <br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray
 W/System.err(2508): at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
W/System.err(2508): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
W/System.err(2508):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
this is the error I got after making the mentioned changes.